# (CMake) PCL + Other libraries

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, libraries, point-cloud-library

**Context :** I am following [this guide](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_pcl_pcl_config.php#using-pcl-pcl-config) to generate my Visual Studio project with the Point Cloud Library PCL, it seems to be the only way to use it.

**Problem :** I have realised that with this method I can not include other libraries like the Bitmap_image.hpp or even the string.h

**I've tried :**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(MY_GRAND_PROJECT)
find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
add_executable(pcd_write_test pcd_write.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pcd_write_test ${PCL_COMMON_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_IO_LIBRARIES} ${string})
```

**The result:**

It generates the project. PCL works perfectly and the line

```
#include <string>
```

does not show error.

But

```
string a;
```

throws "*Error C2065 'string': undeclared identifier*"
and the same happens with other libraries.

**Any solution?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is (basic) C++ knowledge and has nothing to do with any part of the build system.

`#include <string>` pulls in the C++ Standard Library, specifically the container `std::string`. As long as your compiler knows you are compiling C++ (and Visual Studio knows this from the `.cpp` file extension), then it will link a version of the C++ Standard Library for you automatically.

All your calls to these parts of the C++ Standard Library need to be prefixed with `std::` or you need a `using namespace std;` somewhere in your code (the second is generally not recommended though).

In other words, remove `${string}`, since it was not there in the original CMakeLists.txt file you are following (and also means nothing) and use `std::string` in your source code etc.

As for `Bitmap_image.hpp`, you need to indicate where to find it. If it is part of PCL, then that should already be working.

If it is a different library, you will need to learn the basics of CMake to add these libraries. Hint: CMake commands `add_library()` and `target_include_directories()` and `target_link_libraries()`. Also, `target_compile_options()` and `target_compile_definitions()` could be useful.

A good modern introduction to CMake is by [Daniel Pfeifer](https://de.slideshare.net/DanielPfeifer1/cmake-48475415).